# openlayers for mobile devices

Tags: google-maps, mobile, sencha-touch, openlayers, mashup

A newbie question: in mobile web development using openlayers, which lib file do I need to include in the header? I mean, is it openlayers.js or openlayers.mobile.js?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/OpenLayers.mobile.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

Will there be some difference in practice?

The reason why I ask this is that I want to develop a mashup app with GoogleMaps; however, if I don't include openlayers.js but instead put openlayer.mobile, then "Openlayers.layer.Google" won't be recognized.

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default OpenLayers.mobile.js is built with 'mobile.cfg' profile that looks like this:

```
[first]

[last]

[include]
OpenLayers/Map.js
OpenLayers/Kinetic.js
OpenLayers/Projection.js
OpenLayers/Layer/SphericalMercator.js
OpenLayers/Layer/XYZ.js
OpenLayers/Layer/Bing.js
OpenLayers/Layer/WMS.js
OpenLayers/Format/WMSGetFeatureInfo.js
OpenLayers/Control/TouchNavigation.js
OpenLayers/Control/Geolocate.js
OpenLayers/Control/ZoomPanel.js
OpenLayers/Control/Attribution.js
OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature.js
OpenLayers/Control/DrawFeature.js
OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature.js
OpenLayers/Control/WMSGetFeatureInfo.js
OpenLayers/Control/Panel.js
OpenLayers/Handler/Point.js
OpenLayers/Handler/Path.js
OpenLayers/Handler/Polygon.js
OpenLayers/Layer/Vector.js
OpenLayers/Layer/TileCache.js
OpenLayers/Renderer/SVG.js
OpenLayers/Renderer/Canvas.js
OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON.js
OpenLayers/Format/KML.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/HTTP.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS/v1_0_0.js
OpenLayers/Strategy/Fixed.js

[exclude]
```

As you can see there is no OpenLayers.Layer.Google in it. That's why you're getting error.
So I would recommend you to go ahead and build your own version of OpenLayers that would contain only stuff you need(you might want, for instance, remove OpenLayers.Layer.Bing).

[Here is a good guide](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html) of how you do it.

Comment: very good advice. but why not just include the whole "openlayers.js"? do you think all of the features in "openlayers.js" could be well supported in mobile devices? thanks!

Comment: simply because mobile users are usually on mobile internet connection which is not fast and to load whole OpenLayers library(about 1 mb) can take quite a while. I didn't try all openlayers features on mobile devices, but the most common ones like showing different types of layers, drawing, measuring, etc. should work.